# Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an instance using ServiceLocator

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the MediaPlayer property.
/// </summary>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic", Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
public MediaPlayerViewModel MediaPlayer
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MediaPlayerViewModel>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

but i get the following excpetion:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled
>   by user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Activation error occurred
>   while trying to get instance of type MediaPlayerViewModel, key ""
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   53
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstanceTService
>   in
>   c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   90
>          at Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.get_MediaPlayer()
>   in c:\Users\ekreiczer\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\player\Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:line
>   73   InnerException:
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
>          HResult=-2146233088
>          Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI.ViewModel.MediaPlayerViewModel", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI.Services.IDialogService, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I don't know how to type map, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaPlayerViewModel` most likely depends on an implementation of `Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI.Services.IDialogService`.

Look at the constructor and the properties of `MediaPlayerViewModel` to verify that.

You forgot to map `Verint.PI2.MediaPlayer.UI.Services.IDialogService` to an implementation in your bootstrapper.

Comment: I'm new to this kind of programming, can you please advise on how to map?

Comment: The constructor indeed depends on IDialogService